# How to open ASP.NET page using Shortcut Keys in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, shortcut

I am developing an ASP.NET web application. in which have a home page, 
when we press <kbd>F2</kbd> in home page we need to load item Master page & 
when press F4 in home page we need to load city Master page.

I don't know how to open these pages in ASP.NET `C#` using short cut keys..

Can any one help me?

Comment: You mean you are trying to create links to open the pages?

Comment: yes i am trying to open pages using keys without clicking the menu..

Comment: I've updated my answer. See the link.

Answer (score 0):

write a javascript code onkeypress

```
 function keypress() {
        switch (event.keyCode) {
        case ascii of f2:
           //redirect/or load item master
        }
    }
```

or

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  document.attachEvent('onkeyup', KeysShortcut);


// Now implement the KeysShortcut
function KeysShortcut ()

{

    if (event.keyCode == 49)

    {
      document.getElementById('<%= button1.ClientID %>').click();

    }

}
  </script>
```

Using linkbutton Example...

C#

Note : The javascript, depending on the keycode, invokes the click event of the element, in our case the link button. The element is obtained by using `document.getElementById(' '<%=Control.ClientID%>'').`

Note: While using Master Pages, you need to refer to the control using the control's ClientID. I have directly used the ID generated.

```
<head runat="server">
    <title>Untitled Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="shortcut.js"> </script>
</head>
```

Page 1

Add a javascript file to the project called shortcut.js. Add the following code to the javascript file.

```
 function HomeKey()
    {
        if(event.keyCode == 72)
    {     

   document.getElementById('ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_btnHome').click();
    }
        }
```

now on backside

```
C#
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.GetType(), "Home", "document.attachEvent('onkeyup',HomeKey);", true);
}
```

Comment: The OP wants it with C#, not JavaScript.

Comment: sir, i am using these types of the following menu's..  <ul class="sub">
         <li runat="server" id="MnuItem" visible="true"><a href="ItemMaster.aspx">Item</a></li>
        <li runat="server" id="MnuCity" visible="true"><a href="CityMaster.aspx">City</a></li>
        </ul>

Comment: <a id="xyz" href="ItemMaster.aspx">Item</a>

document.getElementById('xyz').click();